# Rails gem naming convention

Tags: ruby, rubygems, naming-conventions

Suppose there is Foo service and it has RESTful API. If I want to create wrapper lib for it:

```
bundle gem foo-api-client
```

Then it creates following structure:

```
foo-api-client/Gemfile
foo-api-client/Rakefile
foo-api-client/LICENSE.txt
foo-api-client/README.md
foo-api-client/.gitignore
foo-api-client/foo-api-client.gemspec
foo-api-client/lib/foo/api/client.rb
foo-api-client/lib/foo/api/client/version.rb
```

I don't need separately api module, and I wonder should I leave it or maybe try to change to:
fooapi-client/lib/fooapi/client.rb

Is there some naming convention for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bundle gem` is trying to build a structure that matches naming conventions as advised [on the Rubygems website](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/)

Table of example names taken from the link:

```
Gem name               Require statement             Main class or module
fancy_require          require 'fancy_require'          FancyRequire
ruby_parser            require 'ruby_parser'            RubyParser
net-http-persistent    require 'net/http/persistent'    Net::HTTP::Persistent
rdoc-data              require 'rdoc/data'              RDoc::Data
autotest-growl         require 'autotest/growl'         Autotest::Growl
net-http-digest_auth   require 'net/http/digest_auth'   Net::HTTP::DigestAuth
```

That this is deliberate behaviour of bundler is backed up by [comments on issue 1255](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1255)

As for naming your client, I'd probably suggest `bundle gem foo_api_client` unless your client is an extension for an existing `foo` gem. Although a suitable pun on the gem's purpose or history is often acceptable in the Ruby community.

Comment: Interesting, so a gem which adds custom matchers to rspec, not written by the author of rspec, should be named rspec_custom rather than rspec-custom, correct? Because rspec-custom will place Custom in the Rspec namespace opening up the possibility of conflicts.

Comment: @DogWeather: That depends on a few things. Some published gems encourage use of a specific namespace for extensions. Others it may have become accepted practice to do so, and rely on good will of all contributors. For an active project like RSpec, it also does no harm to ask the development team for opinion.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I've DM'd the RSpec lead for an opinion.